# Python RPG: finding if an enemy is within a player's range

Tags: python, coordinates

In an RPG I am making, in the main game loop, I need to check if at any time a creature is within the 4-space range of a player (user) so I can initiate/ call the `battle_loop` function.

I have a class `Creature` which is used for all of the enemies, which has attributes `PosX` and `PosY`. (These coordinates are included when initializing a new instance of Creature, and are never changed). The player also has PosX and PosY variables of its own, which can change upon the player moving around.

So is there a way that I can check if any instance of Creature's PosX value is within two less or two more than the player's PosX value and if any instance of Creature's PosY value is within two more or two less of the player's PosY value?

Comment: Do you want 2D distance (`sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2)`) or Manhattan distance (`dx + dy`) or some other metric?

Comment: `if player.x - 2 <= creature.x <= player.x + 2 and player.y - 2 <= creature.y <= player.y + 2:`?

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain a list of `Creature` objects and loop through them.  For each `Creature`, calculate the distance from the player and call `battle_loop` accordingly:

```
for creature in creatures:
    if abs(creature.x - player.x) <= 2 and abs(creature.y - player.y) <= 2:
        battle_loop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just run a for loop.

```
for creature in creatureList:
```

Then do something like this:

```
if (creature.PosX > self.PosX - 2 & creature.PosX < self.PosX + 2) : doSomething()
```

...and a similar one for the y-values. The if statement will return true if the creature is within 2 x and 2 y of the player.

Answer (score 0):

This is common, what you may want is to calculate either the [Manhattan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) or [euclidean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) distance between the two location points (x,y), depending on how creatures can move in your game.